# how to share or symlink a directory in Apache so multiple virtual hosts can access it

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a media directory located on the same host as my Apache  server, that I want all my sites to have access to. Read access is fine. Potential issue is that I am running mod_ruid. This is on my own dedicated centos server with whm/cpanel. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) directive which allows documents to be stored in the local filesystem other than under the `DocumentRoot`. So basically you can make an `alias` directive for every site and they will be able to access the same source.